# Showing that the intersection of all subgroups of order $n$ is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have been thinking about this problem:

"Suppose that a group $G$ has a subgroup of order $n$.  Prove that the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ of order $n$ is a normal subgroup of $G$."

Unfortunately, I don't have much of a start.  I know that the intersection will be a subgroup of each of the subgroups of order $n$, and thus will have order dividing $n$.  I also know that conjugation preserves the order of elements, which suggests that $xNx^{-1}$ could be a subset of $N$ ($N$ being the intersection of all subgroups of order $n$), but I don't see why conjugation necessarily takes elements of $N$ to other elements of $N$.

I'd really appreciate a *hint* on how to go about showing this.  Thanks.

Comment: Fix an $x$, then the map $a \rightarrow xax^{-1}$ is an isomorphism. What happens to a subgroup of order $n$ under an isomorphism?

Comment: Note that you have a Characteristic subgroup - which is a stronger property, because every automorphism (including conjugation) permutes the subgroups of order $n$.

Comment: Could someone take a look at my comment under the answer?  I'd like a response.

Comment: A nice answer to this was given in February 2010 here: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100219223444AAfdd2N

Answer (score 11):

Hint: Conjugation permutes the set of subgroups of order $n$.

Comment: Alright, I see that.  I'm still not quite seeing it though.  Not all subgroups of order $n$ have to be isomorphic, so I guess taking the intersection kind of accounts for that.  So then restricting conjugation to the intersection results in an automorphism so that $xNx^{-1} \subseteq N$?

Answer (score 1):

All group structure-related property is preserved in automophisms. So inner automophism just permutes conjugacy class. and intersection is preserved. so conjugation of elements of intersection subgroup is simply mapped onto intersection group.

Answer (score 0):

Let G be a group, and let H be the intersection of all subgroups of G that have a given order k. We need to show that H is a normal subgroup of G.

First, note that H is a subgroup of G, since it is the intersection of subgroups. To see this, let A and B be subgroups of G of order k, and consider their intersection A ∩ B. Since A and B are subgroups, we know that A ∩ B is closed under multiplication and contains the identity element. Moreover, since A and B are subgroups of G, any element in A ∩ B is also in G, and so A ∩ B is a subset of G. Thus, A ∩ B is a subgroup of G. Now, by taking the intersection of all such subgroups, we obtain H, which is also a subgroup of G.

Next, we need to show that H is a normal subgroup of G, i.e., that for any g in G, gHg^(-1) is contained in H. To see this, note that since H is the intersection of all subgroups of G of order k, it is contained in any such subgroup. In particular, since H is a subgroup of G, it is contained in the subgroup generated by gHg^(-1) for any g in G. But this subgroup also has order k, since it contains gHg^(-1) and hence contains at most k distinct elements. Therefore, H is contained in the subgroup generated by gHg^(-1) for any g in G, which implies that gHg^(-1) is contained in H.

Hence, we have shown that H is a normal subgroup of G

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Why do you claim that “since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, it is contained in the subgroup generated by $gHg^{-1}$ for any $g \in G$”? Anyway, this question was posted and answered ten years ago. I suggest that you focus on new questions.