# Show the intersection of six subgroups of order $24$ is normal in $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group with exactly six subgroups of order $24$. Show that
>   the intersection of these six subgroups is normal in $G$.

My thought is that if we can show these six subgroups are normal themselves, then the intersection being normal follows trivially but I don't know how to show the six subgroups are normal. Perhaps something to do with their order?

What's a good way to prove this theorem?

Note: This similar question, [Showing that the intersection of all subgroups of order n is normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472498/showing-that-the-intersection-of-all-subgroups-of-order-n-is-normal), hints to use conjugation but I'm looking for a more complete answer.

Comment: The "similar" question answers your question; check the answers and several comments again.

Comment: The best answer would convince you that it couldn't be anything but *characteristic* in $G$, hence normal. (The subgroups being intersected need not be normal at all and the result is still true, don't take that path!)

Answer (score 3):

Let $H_1, \ldots, H_6$ denote your subgroups of order $24$, and let $H$ be the intersection of these subgroups. Now consider any $g \in G$. We need to show that $gHg^{-1} = H$.

Consider the six sets $gH_1g^{-1}, \ldots, gH_6g^{-1}$. These sets are six distinct subgroups of order $24$ in $G$, since $h \mapsto ghg^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $G$. Now since $H_1, \ldots, H_6$ are the only subgroups of order $24$, they must necessarily be the same six subgroups as $gH_1g^{-1}, \ldots, gH_6g^{-1}$ (not necessarily in the same order).

Therefore we have $gHg^{-1} = gH_1g^{-1} \cap \ldots \cap gH_6g^{-1} = H_1 \cap \ldots \cap H_6 = H$.

Extra info: $H$ is not only a normal subgroup, but in fact a characteristic subgroup (invariant under all automorphisms, not just those of the form $h \mapsto ghg^{-1}$). We showed that $H$ is invariant under inner automorphisms, but the exact same principle works for outer automorphisms too.